# Create a XML with a XSD using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have this class in java that I created automatically using xjc, based on a xsd file:

```
 public class Item{

    @XmlAttribute(name = "id_item", required = true)
    protected String idInstitution;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "item_name", required = true)
    protected String itemName;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id_language")
    protected String idLanguage;
```

`//geters and setters ommited`

As you can see there are atributes that are required,but I created a xml file without those atributes,I thought that wasn't possible,what Im I doing wrong?

Here is the xml that I created:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ItemList>
   <Item item_name="test" />
</ItemList>
```

And here is how I created the xml:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public void createXML(@RequestBody ItemList list) throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException {

    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Item.class);

    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

    marshaller.marshal(list, System.out);

}
```

Comment: `I thought that wasn't possible`. Nah, JAXB doesn't care. The question of whether something is required or not is a validation question, and JAXB doesn't validate, it makes. In practice the "required" parameter is there to be closer to a 1:1 map between Java annotations and XSD format. But it doesn't actually serve a purpose, at least as long as you're not going to try and use the Java class to validate data, which is not a thing done.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this tool to create xml from xsd.
http://xsd2xml.com

Maybe you could figure out how to make an API Call to it to achieve your purposes.